# Bat file move files

Tags: batch, batch-file

I need to create a bat file to move files from folder 1 to folder 2. however, I need to keep in folder 1 the files created in the lasts 3 hours. all the rest old files must be move to folder 2. I´ve been trying with this but I have the issue related to "PM was unexpected at this time"

```
@echo off
set "source_folder=C:\Users\florem26\Desktop\Current\"
set "destination_folder=C:\Users\florem26\Desktop\Archived\"
set "age_threshold=3.00"

forfiles /p "C:\Users\florem26\Desktop\Current" /s /m * /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE if @ftime < %%time:~0,3%%time:~3,2%-%age_threshold% echo move @path "C:\Users\florem26\Desktop\Archived"
pause
```

---

The issue persist, is the following "AM/PM was unexpected at this time" it seems an issue with dates or time, not sure about it.

Comment: Run it without `@echo off` and watch where this is happening. Please be exact about the error message.

Comment: Does `RoboCopy` support this via `/MinAge` _(I'm unsure if it supports min/hrs or only days/dates since there's [no syntax example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy))_?